# How to keep both emails in the footer on the same line?

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

When I increase the scales to `left=4cm, right=3cm`, the second email in the footer goes to the next line. So, with the same scales as in the following letter template, how can I keep both emails in the footer on the same line, that is, how to **prevent the second email** from going the next line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                             
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                  
\email{rre8wwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}

The body of the letter

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}      

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one possibility is to change the defined width for the footer (`0.8\textwidth`) to be a little bit longer.

In `moderncvfooti.sty` you will find the definition

```
% lengths
\@initializelength{\footwidth}%
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
```

Add the following code to your preambel with a changed width:

```
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.85\textwidth}} % original: 0.8\textwidth
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=3cm,showframe]{geometry} % left=4cm, right=3cm  left=2cm, right=1cm

\usepackage{blindtext} % to generate dummy text <===========================

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}

% lengths
%\@initializelength{\footwidth}%
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{% <======================================
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.85\textwidth}} % original: 0.8\textwidth <==========


\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
% personal data
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{rre8wwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing

    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    


The body of the letter

\blindtext

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}


\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: the new footer]

In version 1.3.0 of `moderncv`are the footer for cv (command `\makecvfooter`) and letter (`\makeletterfooter`) defined in file `moderncvstylecasual.sty`.

To change command `\makeletterfooter` you can use the following code:

```
\patchcmd{\makeletterfooter}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.85\textwidth}}{}{} % <==========
```

((And if you need it to change command `\makecvfooter`:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvfooter}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.85\textwidth}}{}{} % <==========
```

With the following MWE only for the usage with version 1.3.0

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=3cm,showframe]{geometry} % left=4cm, right=3cm  left=2cm, right=1cm

\usepackage{blindtext} % to generate dummy text <===========================

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}

\patchcmd{\makeletterfooter}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}}{\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.85\textwidth}}{}{} % <==========

\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
% personal data
\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Templeton} % Your last name
\title{Resumé title}
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}
\mobile{+19193433283}
\email{rre8wwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing

    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    


The body of the letter

\blindtext

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}


\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution!

Comment: Weird, It does not work here. It says: LaTeX Error: \recomputefootlengths undefined. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                              
                                                 
l.29 \renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}
                                          {%